# jQuery removing <option> tags that it shouldn't be removing

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a number of dynamic `<select>` elements that are generated based on various user inputs.  I'm trying to remove certain `<option>`'s that are not applicable for each select but jQuery seems to remove more `<option>`'s then it should be removing based on my code.  A full use case would be difficult to reproduce, so I'll post what I'm seeing and hopefully that will be good enough to figure this one out.

To prove to myself that I'm not crazy I decided to add a class instead of remove the `<option>` in the loop.  Here's what I used:

```
$('.my-select').each(function(sourceIdx,sourceEl){
 var id = $(sourceEl).attr('id');
 var s = $('#'+id).parents('table').find('.some-input').val();
 $(sourceEl).find('option[value="'+s+'"]').addClass('option-remove');
});
```

Here's the generated source:

```
<select class="my-select" id="1295453461993">
 <option title="1" value="1">1</option>
 <option title="2" value="2" class="option-remove">2</option>
 <option title="3" value="3">3</option>
</select> 

<select class="my-select" id="1295453475890">
 <option title="1" value="1">1</option>
 <option title="2" value="2">2</option>
 <option title="3" value="3" class="option-remove">3</option>
</select>
```

Which is exactly what I'm looking to happen.  However, when I add this immediately following the loop:

```
$('.option-remove').remove();
```

I get this:

```
<select class="my-select" id="1295454051124">
 <option title="1" value="1">1</option>
</select>

<select class="my-select" id="1295454058398">
 <option title="1" value="1">1</option>
 <option title="2" value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Which makes me say: "Wait, WHAT?!".  It *appears* that when jQuery removes the `<option>` in the 2nd select it removes that same `<option>` (value=3) from the first `<select>`.  Not cool.

So what might I be doing wrong here?

I'm testing in FireFox 3.5 (same results in IE) with jQuery 1.4.4.

Comment: I can't reproduce this (see [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/evomi4/edit)). Where exactly did you put `$('.option-remove').remove()`? And I can't understand that `$(sourceEl).find('option[value="'+s+'"]')` can apply to both `value="2"` *and* `value="3"`.

Comment: Yeah me neither..Can you post the full HTML..

Comment: The second select is created dynamically by copying the html() of a much larger block of code and appending it to the outer container.  I'm wondering if that is what's confusing jQuery?

Comment: Then you should show the result of that copy, because the error is not in the posted markup.

Comment: That is the result of the copy...

Comment: Figured it out.  I was modifying the value before this block so stupid error on my part.  Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A stripped-down, non-dynamic test case works fine:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<form>
<select class="my-select" id="1295453461993">
  <option title="1" value="1">1</option>
  <option title="2" value="2" class="option-remove">2</option>
  <option title="3" value="3">3</option>
</select> 

<select class="my-select" id="1295453475890">
  <option title="1" value="1">1</option>
  <option title="2" value="2">2</option>
  <option title="3" value="3" class="option-remove">3</option>
</select>
</form>

<script>
  $('.option-remove').remove();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

There must be something else going on...

Comment: I agree. I created this on jsfiddle and it works fine in Chrome & FF (didn't try IE). http://jsfiddle.net/jdowdle/kDeYF/1/

Comment: The second select is created dynamically by copying the html() of a much larger block of code and appending it to the outer container. I'm wondering if that is what's confusing jQuery?

Comment: Figured it out.  I was modifying the value before this block so stupid error on my part.

Comment: Marking as 'correct' answer cuz you nailed it - 'something else was going on'... thanks for the sanity check.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't know a solution for your problem, i may have help. Maybe this makes your life easier -> https://github.com/SamWM/jQuery-Plugins/tree/master/selectboxes

I used it and it worked quite well. And it isn't such a big plugin, so no big overhead.

Answer (score 0):

> > $(sourceEl).find('option[value="'+s+'"]').addClass('option-remove');

just curious, what if you used this instead?

```
$('#' + id).find('option ...
```

i.e. by the id, rather than by the element passed into the function

or

```
$('#' + id + '> option[value="'+s+'"}')
```

i.e. one big selector, rather than 'find'

> > The second select is created dynamically by copying the html()

are you giving it a unique ID when it is copied?

Comment: just re-read initial post and realized that the issue is not with the assigning of the class, i.e. your targeting is working as expected.

could you pass the ID of the select into the function here? 

>> $('.option-remove').remove(); 

something like 

$('#' + id + '> .option-remove').remove();

?

Comment: also just curious - have you tried anything other than 'remove' ... like, try .hide(), or script the name of the thing into the console ... i always try to troubleshoot jquery methods like remove() by using another method, just to make sure the right elements are being targeted by my script in general, and bypass anything method-specific. Otherwise, i dunno man, this is a weird one.